# make android app fullscreen in landscape mode only

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation, android-fullscreen

Normally, to make my app fullscreen, inside the `onCreate`, before `setContentView` I do

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

But I have a situation where I need to enable fullscreen in landscape orientation -- but not in portrait. However, doing as below throws an exception concerning `setContentView`. So how do I do this correctly?

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            attachViewPager();
        }else{
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            detachViewPager();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe it will help you

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: ?? Then what happens for later versions? I am testing on a Galaxy S5 running Lollipop. And by default I don't get fullscreen in landscape.

Comment: i didn't try on older version but m sure if you use requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); it will work for them

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. But you really misread the question. My app can operate in both portrait and landscape mode. When the phone is in landscape mode, I want fullscreen; when it is not in landscape mode, I **do not** want fullscreen. I am controlling orientation by overriding `onConfigurationChanged` for other reasons as well, such as `attachViewPager` as shown in the question.